# Populate data based on the response given in Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I have created two sections

First Section I have Order ID after entering the order ID and I click Next - In second section I want to populate order id's related data like (Name, Address, list of orders) All these data are available in an excel sheet, Once it is populated I would like the user to confirm their orders are correct and then hit submit.

Is this possible using google form or any add-ons for Google forms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i read your question

As far i know about google form, google form don't give option to recheck your pre-filled options. So, what we can do is to give a confirm button at the end which is must required to fill.

You can see it through this example.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSchhhCjcyQe-ZTdl8pFF-ETLPGFTXPcuqQGDGQ1nMbtcwOnGQ/viewform?usp=sf_link

If you want to create a more user defined form you can make it from simple html and php.

hope this will help you.
thanks!